# Not getting HTTP Response Status in Icecast

Tags: actionscript-3, icecast

I'm having an issue with not getting my HTTP response in AS3 to an Icecast server.

```
vidstream = new URLStream();
vidstream.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, videoStream_responseHandler);
vidstream.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, videoStream_responseHandler);
vidstream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, videoStream_progressHandler);
var pRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(
    "XXXX"
);
pRequest.requestHeaders = new Array(
    new URLRequestHeader("Icy-MetaData", "1")
);
vidstream.load(pRequest);
```

I get the progress handler events, and I've verified that I get the headers through something like an  HTML tag, but I'm just not getting the event to fire in AS3.

Comment: Set up some packet sniffing and see if the HTTP request is going through at all.

Comment: It turns out that Flash cannot receive HTTP headers.  The HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS is Adobe Air only.